# System.Linq.Dynamic .Select("new ...") does not appear to be thread safe

Tags: multithreading, linq-to-sql

I grabbed System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable from here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

The issue that I am running into is in code that looks like this:

```
var results = dataContext.GetTable<MyClass>.Select("new (MyClassID, Name, Description)").Take(5);
```

It appears that if that line of code is executed by multiple threads near simultaneously, Microsoft's dynamic Linq code crashes in their ClassFactory.GetDynamicClass() method, which looks like this:

```
    public Type GetDynamicClass(IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> properties)
    {
        rwLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        try
        {
            Signature signature = new Signature(properties);
            Type type;
            if (!classes.TryGetValue(signature, out type))
            {
                type = CreateDynamicClass(signature.properties);
                classes.Add(signature, type);  // <-- crashes over here!
            }
            return type;
        }
        finally
        {
            rwLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }
```

The crash is a simple dictionary error: "An item with the same key has already been added."

In Ms code, The rwLock variable is a ReadWriterLock class, but it does nothing to block multiple threads from getting inside classes.TryGetValue() if statement, so clearly, the Add will fail.

I can replicate this error pretty easily in any code that creates a two or more threads that try to execute the Select("new") statement.

Anyways, I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this issue, and if there are fixes or workarounds I can implement.

Thanks.

Comment: since you have the source you could effectively fix this by exchanging the `Dictionary` with the `ConcurrentDictionary` - this would be rather fast (most operations are implemented lock-free) and solve the thread issue (since it is thread-safe)

Comment: It's clearly a bug.  Good thing that you can fix it, use UpgradeToWriterLock() before calling Add.

Comment: Simply upgrading to write lock is not enough, you need to check (try to get) the value *again* after the X lock is obtained.

Comment: I "think" I fixed it by changing the rwLock.AcquireReaderLock() call to rwLock.AcquireWriterLock(), and also the subsequent Release call.  I'm probably paying a small performance hit, but my guess is it is too small to be noticable.  I guess I was hoping that someone had run into this and there is a more "official" fix out there I should take in case there are other bugs fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following (requires .NET 4 or later to use `System.Collections.Concurrent`):

- changed the `classes` field to a `ConcurrentDictionary<Signature, Type>` ,
- removed all the `ReaderWriterLock rwLock` field and all the code referring to it,
- updated `GetDynamicClass` to:

  ```
  public Type GetDynamicClass(IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> properties) {
      var signature = new Signature(properties);
      return classes.GetOrAdd(signature, sig => CreateDynamicClass(sig.properties));
  }
  ```
- removed the `classCount` field and updated `CreateDynamicClass` to use `classes.Count` instead:

  ```
  Type CreateDynamicClass(DynamicProperty[] properties) {
      string typeName = "DynamicClass" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
  ...
  ```

Comment: There's still a potential race condition here, since you read classes.Count without a lock. You could potentially get two classes created with the same numeral suffix. A safer approach would be to use "DynamicClass" + Guid.NewGuid().